# New column in DataFrame from other columns AND rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column, V, in an existing DataFrame, df. I would like the value of the new column to be the difference between the value in the 'x' column in that row, and the value of the 'x' column in the row below it.

As an example, in the picture below, I want the value of the new column to be
93.244598 - 93.093285 = 0.151313.

I know how to create a new column based on existing columns in Pandas, but I don't know how to reference other rows using this method. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve iterating over the rows in the dataframe? (since I have read that this is generally a bad idea)

[image: DataFrame I want to modify]

Comment: please provide a **minimal** example of the dataset as **text**. Also provide the code you used and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for your use case.

The last row will not have any row to subtract from so you will get the value for that cell as `NaN`

```
df['temp_x'] = df['x'].shift(-1)
df[`new_col`] = df['x'] - df['temp_x']
```

or one liner :

```
df[`new_col`] = df['x'] - df['x'].shift(-1)
```

the column `new_col` will contain the expected data

Answer (score 1):

An ideal solution is to use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['new'] = df['x'].diff(-1)
```